# Enumerating the bound arguments using bind

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, can I enumerate the bound arguments for a function?

```
function foo(a, b) {}

foo = foo.bind(null, '1');
```

How can I tell that a has been bound to '1'?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. However, here is a hacky way to get all currently bound arguments of a function.

It works by overwriting the native bind method and storing all bound arguments in a property of the newly bound function.

```
Function.prototype.bind = (function() {
    var bind = Function.prototype.bind;
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    return function() {
        // bind the function using the native bind
        var bound = bind.apply(this, arguments);

        // store the bound arguments in a property of the bound function
        bound.bArgs = (this.bArgs || []).concat(slice.call(arguments, 1));

        return bound;
    };
})();

function foo(a, b) {}

foo = foo.bind(null, '1');
console.log(foo.bArgs); // ["1"]

foo = foo.bind(null, '2');
console.log(foo.bArgs); // ["1", "2"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49d1xfns/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The function is simply being called passed a certain `this` value and optionally certain argument values: it's not a problem of the called function to distinguish **who** has been passing those values...

To simplify a bit the issue consider:

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

function bind_first(f, x) {
    return function(y) { return f(x, y); };
}

var add3 = bind_first(add, 3);
console.log(add3(2)); // ==> output is 5
```

the `add` function is called with two arguments as usual... both of them are coming from the body of an anonymous closure created by `bind_first` and it's it's nothing that should interest `add` how this anonymous closure computed the value of those parameters... got them from the outside? were captured variables? computed them itself? are constants?... WHO CARES!

In other words if you want to be able to differentiate between a bound argument and a regular argument there's for sure something wrong in your design (it's none of your business :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

To know how many explicit arguments were bound to a particular function, you'd need to know:

- The number of explicit arguments in the original function
- The number of explicit arguments in the bound function

This can be achieved if you have access to both the original function and the newly bound function. This also assumes that the binding was done with an ES5 compliant `Function.prototype.bind` call.

The way you'd figure out which arguments were bound is by subtracting the newly bound function's length from the original function's length:

```
var foo = function (a, b, c) {...};
var bar = foo.bind(fizz, buzz);
var argumentsBound = foo.length - bar.length; // 1
var argumentNames = ['a', 'b', 'c'].slice(0, argumentsBound); // 'a'
```

Details for why this works can be found in the [ES5 spec (15.3.4.5, #15)](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5)

> 15. If the [[Class]] internal property of *Target* is "Function", then
>
>     1. Let *L* be the length property of *Target* minus the length of *A*.
>     2. Set the length own property of *F* to either 0 or *L*, whichever is larger.

All of that said, this doesn't give much access at all to which properties were bound, and is pretty well useless within the original function (`foo` in my example above) because the original function probably shouldn't reference bound derivative functions.

This also doesn't help at all if no arguments are defined on the function. If you're making use of `arguments` to pass additional parameters, the `length` property is no longer relevant.